# Power series of the solution of $2t^2x'' + tx' -(t+1)x=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

> Use the method of Frobenius, with the larger root of the indicial
>   equation, to find the first three terms of the power series of the solution to $$2t^2x'' +
>  tx' -(t+1)x=0.$$

My work:

Note that $t=0$ is a regular singular point. On solving the indicial equation, we get $r=1$ or $r=-\frac12$. We proceed by letting $$x(t) = t^r \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k t^k$$ which, after plugging into the equation, yields $$(ra_1 - a_0)t^{r+1} - a_0 t^r + \sum_{n=r+2}^{\infty} [(2n^2-n-1)a_{n-r} - a_{n-r-1}]t^n=0.$$ However, I cannot proceed. The above with $r=1$ would imply that all coefficients are zero. The calculation should be fine as several of my friends also get the same answer. **Should we conclude that the first three terms are all zero?**

Comment: Using $r=1$, it seems to me that effectively all coefficients are equal to $0$. $x(t)=0$ is a solution of the differential equation. The story is totally different using $r=-\frac12$.

Comment: there is nothing to balance $-tx$ in the last term?

Comment: @abel : what do you mean by balancing $-tx$?

Comment: that was an error. i don't have time now. i will take a look at it later.

Comment: $t+(1/5)t^2+(1/70)t^3+\dots$.  Try again plugging in.

Comment: @GEdgar : it is driving me crazy xd Would you mind showing your steps in the answer?

Comment: i posted an answer. take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have $$2t^2x''+tx' - (t+1)x= 0  $$ now sub $$x = t^k + a_1t^{k+1} + a_2 t^{k+2} + \cdots\\
x' = kt^{k-1} + (k+1)a_1t^k + (k+2)a_2t^{k+1} + \cdots\\ 
x'' = (k-1)kt^{k-2} + k(k+1)a_1t^{k-1} + (k+1)(k+2)a_2t^{k} + \cdots$$ we get
$$2t^2\left(  (k-1)kt^{k-2} + k(k+1)a_1t^{k-1} + (k+1)(k+2)a_2t^{k} + \cdots\right) + t\left( kt^{k-1} + (k+1)a_1t^k + (k+2)a_2t^{k+1} + \cdots\right)- (t+1)\left( t^k + a_1t^{k+1} + a_2 t^{k+2} + \cdots\right) =0$$

equating the coefficient of $t^{k}$ we have

$$f(k)=2(k-1)k +k-1=(k-1)(2k+1)=0 \to k = 1, k = -\frac 12.$$

equating the coefficient of $t^{k+1}$ we have

$$2k(k+1)a_1+(k+1)a_1 -a_1-1=0\to a_1 = \frac 1{f(k+1)} $$
in the same way you find $$a_2 =  \frac {a_1}{f(k+2)}, \cdots, a_{n+1}=\frac {a_n}{f(n+k)}, = n = 1, 2, \cdots $$

let us look at the series for the case $k = 0$

$$a_1 = \frac 1{f(2)} = \frac 1{1 \cdot 5}\\
a_2 = \frac {a_1}{f(3)}=\frac 1{1\cdot 2 \cdot 5 \cdot 7}\\
a_3 = \frac{a_2} {f(4)}=\frac 1{1\cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 9} \\
\vdots$$

Comment: Thanks for replying. Indeed we are doing the same thing, except the fact that i am using summation...
is that a reason for you not to use summation?

Comment: @LeeKM, summation notation, i find, sometimes obscures what is going on. once i see the pattern, i may go back to the generic terms and the summation notation. i tend to make lots careless errors with the summation notation. that is the reason i prefer the longhand notation.

Comment: When the goal is "find the first three terms", then probably summation notation is more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 1):

Plugging into the equation:
$$
a_0(2r+1)(r-1)t^r + (2a_1r^2+3a_1r-a_0)t^{r+1} +(2a_2r^2+7a_2r+5a_2-a_1)t^{r+2}+\dots
$$
So with $r=1$ (or $r=-1/2$) the first term goes away.  That is why you choose a root of the indicial equation.  Anything else will have a first term there, leading to $a_0 = 0$.  If you get $a_0=0$, it means **you have made a mistake**.